# Getting another process's DirectX backbuffer

Tags: wpf, directx, multiprocessing

I have a WPF application and a separate DirectX process. I would like to be able to get that process's directx device pointer or backbuffer so that I can render it again into my WPF app. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to do this other than by injecting code into the other process to hook it's buffer creation which it not at all a trivial thing to do.... I might be wrong though so it's a comment/opinion, not an answer.